# Modification to Travelling Salesman

Tags: algorithm, np

I am currently learning about optimization algorithms for the travelling salesman problem, and I was wondering if the problem could be modified without changing the actual problem itself.  If that sounds vague, let me clarify:

The **decision** version of TSP, as I understand it, asks the following:

> Given a list of vertices G and a cost c, is there a Hamiltonian path P such that the cost of P is at most c?

I understand the generalities, and the NP-completeness of, this question.  However, I found a modified version of the question more intuitive to think about:

> Given a list of vertices G and a specific Hamiltonian path P, is there a different Hamiltonian path P* such that the cost of P* is less than P?

The parameters are slightly different; the first only gives a total cost, whereas the second gives the entire sequence of vertices that forms that cost.  What I was wondering is, can the first question be reduced to the second without loss of generality?  Obviously, the second can be reduced to the first by simply calculating the cost of P; however, reducing the first to the second escaped my grasp.  Any help in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is not about the P Programming language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 0):

The reduction would require the evaluation the shortest path of cost strictly greater than c.

This operation is at least as hard as the original TSP, because TSP can reduce to it by setting c = 0 and asking whether the path returned is greater than the desired c.

Therefore the reduction is itself NP-hard. Nonetheless it can be formed by using repeated application of the original TSP (which returns the path), increasing c gradually by the smallest difference in edge length present in the graph, starting at one step higher than the c you want for your original question.